How to insert Image in middle of text block in Viva Engage Posts/ Viva Answers
In Viva Answers,
Is there way I can insert image like below ( Image in middle of the text )
enter image description here
This is text after image
Also, can we add Markdown like below?
h1 Heading 8-)
h2 Heading
Also, Can we format code like below
var TestMethod = function () {
    var _cur = this;
    this.GetPropertyValue = function (requestIn, key, defaultValue) {
        var propertyValue = "";
        for (var prop in requestIn) {
            if (key.toLowerCase() == prop.toLowerCase()) {
                propertyValue = requestIn[prop];
                break;
            }
        }
 }

Tried to attach image in middle of the text but when posting its appearing in the bottom.

Like other websites try to add [[IMAGE]] between H1 and H2
